# Extracting text using python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

but have referencing this site for many years.
I'm trying to extract the text "CRITICIAL" or any other text which may be in this field:

Source Code:

```
<td id="x-auto-821" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-severity " style="width:63px;" role="gridcell">
   <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-severity"    unselectable="off">CRITICAL</div>
</td>
```

My Code:

```
try:
    severity = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='x-auto-821']/div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-severity']).text
except Exception as e:
    print("\nFAILED to get Severity because of %s\n" % e)
```

I get the exception:

```
FAILED to get Severity because of Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@id='x-auto-821']/div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner']"}
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp_wNe_1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271)
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmp_wNe_1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10280)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp_wNe_1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp_wNe_1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp_wNe_1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
```

Comment: In the error message you have the following XPath: `"//td[@id='x-auto-821']/div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner']"` It doesn't match with class in the div tag, check again the XPath in your code.

Comment: Should I put either ".../div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner'] or /div[@class='x-grid3-col-severity'] but not both?

Comment: I think it should work with both, what I don't quite understand is why the XPath in the error message is different. Anyway, according to your HTML code you can change the XPath from your code to: `severity = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='x-auto-821']/div).text`

Comment: I reran the script thinking I gave the wrong error (since I've been trying numerous variations) and it the code above worked this time.  Thanks for your time.  :)

Comment: Please add the final code as an answer and accept it so this question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: You can also verify your xpath in your browser using `$x("//td[@id='x-auto-821']/div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-severity'])` in your browsers console (activate dev tools, usually F12).